# How to pass value of parent id in child controller in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp-3.0, has-many

I have just started learning cakephp3, so please excuse me for anything wrong.
So I have one table called Projects and Events, so there relation is like one project can have many events.

When the user is adding a new project, he will be redirected to 'add' event in Controller 'events '.

testapp/projects/add --> testapp/events/add

The code in default add.ctp has a dropdown of projects but i want it to be the normal text field with the value of just created project instead of dropdown.

Please tell how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somewhere in your `ProjectsController` you shoud have something like

```
redirect(['action' => 'add', 'controller' => 'Events'])
```

and you should have a variable named `$project` storing a ProjectEntity

just pass the project id to the redirect action

```
redirect(['action' => 'add', 'controller' => 'Events', $project->id])
```

then in your `EventsController` you'll read the value and store it to the Event entity this way

```
function add($project_id)
{
    // Do something
    $event = $this->Events->newEntity();
    $event->project_id = $project_id; 
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.. it worked for me..  :)